# Is it reasonable to have lots of factories in project?

Tags: design-patterns

In my current project, there are lots of Factory Methods,

so when the program begin it has:

```
Init()
{
  RegisterFactory(A1);
  RegisterFactory(A2);
    ...
  //hundreds of Register.
    ...
}
```

Is there any other way to do this? It looks not reasonable.

Comment: Why do you need to register factories?

Comment: I guess you ment Abstract FActories and Simple Factories instead of Factory Methods.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using some dependency injection framework:

- Java: Google Guice, Spring, [more](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection#Java)
- .Net: Spring.NET, [more](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

They usually externalize the burden of registering factories manually and do much more stuff.